# Can the word "Parse" be used in creative writing

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Can I use parse as a verb in this example?

> The clouds began to parse and the day opened up.

Meaning the clouds began to separate from one another and dissolve. Parse is commonly used to describe analyzing text or sentences but can also be defined as to resolve into its elements.

Comment: You would probably raise the hackles of some linguistics nuts, but you can say whatever you want in "creative writing".

Comment: It's certainly attention-catching!  The 'usual' word to use in that context would be "disperse."

Comment: My reaction would be "The clouds began to analyse sentences??"

Comment: [Parse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parse) is normally transitive but not always; as others have said, do what you like. (I've no idea how a cloud would separate into distinct elements rather than just break up into smaller clouds, but you get some pretty funky clouds some places.)

Comment: I would see it as a misprint for "part".